# how to specific volume type on AWS io1 and set provisioned iops via juju deploy with constraints?

Tags: juju

I try to

```
juju set-model-config storage-default-block-source ebs-ssd
```

but volume type is standard type.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a new storage pool.

```
juju create-storage-pool iops ebs volume-type=io1 iops=NNNN
```

where NNNN is IOPS *per GiB*. When you have that, you can use:

```
juju deploy foo --storage bar=iops,50G
```

Comment: I trie but not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I using this command

juju create-storage-pool iops ebs volume-type=io1 iops=NNNN

but when I type juju storage list or juju list-storage or juju storage pool list

It's nothing happened

and type juju status

MODEL    CONTROLLER  CLOUD  VERSION
default  zanroo      aws    2.0-beta11

APP  STATUS  EXPOSED  ORIGIN  CHARM  REV  OS

UNIT  WORKLOAD  AGENT  MACHINE  PORTS  PUBLIC-ADDRESS  MESSAGE

MACHINE  STATE  DNS  INS-ID  SERIES  AZ

and I trie to using

TheBig:~ thebig$ juju deploy mysql --storage bar=iops,50G
Added charm "cs:mysql-55" to the model.
Deploying charm "cs:mysql-55" with the default charm metadata series "trusty".
ERROR cannot add application "mysql": charm "mysql" has no store called "bar"

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: "bar" was a placeholder name. The mysql charm does not currently have support for Juju-managed storage.